# How to alter the deprecated Camera class in Android

Tags: android, android-camera

In a previous way, flashlight feature could be used by using Camera class. But now that the entire Camera and Camera-related classes in android.hardware packages are deprecated, I should alternatively use some other classes in the android.hardware.camera2 package.

Traditionally, I coded the flashlight part like this.

```
// getting camera parameters
private void getCamera() {
    if (camera == null) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            params = camera.getParameters();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

 /*
  * Turning On flash
  */
private void turnOnFlash() {
    if (!isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        // play sound
        playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashOn = true;

        // changing button/switch image
        toggleButtonImage();
     } 

}
```

But now with the new API I'm getting so confused how to use the new one. Can anybody explain?

Comment: I would recommend sticking with the existing `Camera` API through Android 5.1, then switching to [the new flashlight API in Android M](http://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#camera).

Answer (score 1):

for flashlight I advise using the Camera2 API only from Android 6 (api 23), my function for toggling the flashlight looks like

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public void toggleMarshmallowFlashlight(boolean enable) {
    try {
        final CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        final String[] list = manager.getCameraIdList();
        manager.setTorchMode(list[0], enable);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {

    }
}
```